# Swift - Background thread crashes the app with authenthication

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, background-thread, face-id

I am trying to add a Face ID/Touch ID/Code to my App, but I'm having some trouble when I terminate it:
here's the error I get (with slight variations between one run and another, such as the number of the identifier changing):

> Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 12 (0xc), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

I tried following the instructions, but I couldn't figure out what to do.
On the internet I found out that this could be an error caused by iOS 13, but I don't have any device running iOS 12 to test it out.

There isn't any crash log in my settings.

Here's the code causing the error:

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

class LoginController: VController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    let reason = "Identificati"

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { (success, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    context.invalidate()
                    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
                    let dim = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 12
                    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: dim, height: dim)
                    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 6)
                    let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
                    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    print(err!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason) { (success, err) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if success {
                        context.invalidate()
                        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
                        let dim = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 12
                        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: dim, height: dim)
                        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 6)
                        let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
                        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            // Nothing worked
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `terminating the app`?

Comment: I mean double tap on the home button, then scrolling up to basically not having even only in background

Comment: @Vipera74 try to replace unowned with weak.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Call the [`invalidate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514192-invalidate) function on your context after you are done with it.

Comment: As a result, the identifier changed from 12 to 9

Comment: Have you tried setting the breakpoint as the error is suggesting?

Comment: Can you make sure the error goes away if you remove this newly added biometrics functionality?

Comment: The error only goes away when I remove the whole biometrics functionality, yes

Answer (score 0):

Related to this thread: [iOS : Touch Id is not shown when AppDelegate's open url is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379360/ios-touch-id-is-not-shown-when-appdelegates-open-url-is-invoked)

I have similar problem: app crash on terminal when I use authentication. But I haven't gotten any error log at first. Then I remove canEvaluatePolicy(), only keep evaluatePolicy(), then I got error log when app terminal:

> Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-4 "Caller moved to
> background." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Caller moved to
> background.}

And by keywords "Caller moved to background" I found a solution. Seems that if evaluation works only when sceneDidBecomeActive(), app would not crash on terminal. Hope this would help.